# Why does Matplotlib's `imshow` result is not matching with cv2's `imshow`?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to convert an Image to black and white using `opencv-python`. I have tried the following program.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread("path/to/image.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

(thresh, img) = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

cv2.imshow("Image",img)
cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF 
cv2.destroyAllwindows()
```

**Input Image is** :

[image: Input Image]

This program results in an expected output as shown below.

[image: cv2.imshow output]

However, if I use the `matplotlib`'s `imshow` to plot the black and white image, the result is different.

**Program:**

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread("path/to/image.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

(thresh, img) = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image: plt.imshow output]

Is there a reason why there is a difference between these two outputs ?

Python & Modules' version I am using :

`python 3.8.2`

`matplotlib==3.5.1`

`opencv-python==4.6.0.66`

OS : `macOS Monterey version 12.4`

Comment: Those appear to be the same blobs. Are you referring to the plot colors? OpenCV displays  images. What you process is what you see. Matplot lib plots graphs, and uses [color maps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) to change the color of the  information you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it

```
plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you display a simple 2D array with matplotlib, it uses the values as indexes into a color map.  You can provide your own color map, if you want.

Comment: How can I provide a custom color map to make it look like the same output as `cv2`?

Comment: Use the built-in gray colormap